# MySQL won't allow access - "ERROR 1045 (28000)" - newly installed the free Community version on my Macbook

Tags: mysql

I downloaded the MySQL free community version to my macbook running OS 10.15.1, using the DMG download package.  It has installed the program but MySQL won't start, saying I don't have access.  I've tried the command line syntax below, from the MySQL man page, but it doesn't like my credentials.

mysql --user=user_name --password db_name

I get

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'amichael'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Since it's the free package I don't want to buy support from Oracle just to figure this out!

Comment: Then you need to figure out your credentials.

Answer (score 0):

The user is likely to be 'root' rather than 'amichael'.

You can also read the [free documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/osx-installation-pkg.html).

Comment: Thank you!  I used root as the user name and found a way to set a password, using the mac's system preferences menu which includes mysql due to the successful installation.  I'm getting new error messages but I'm moving again.